# Replacing link URL ending strings via MySQL

Tags: mysql

We are about to purchase a site that uses Amazon affiliate links.

Naturally, they have their own affiliate ID, Amazon affiliate links look like this:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/productcode/?tag=affiliateID-20
```

What would be the best way to alter the ending string for these links' URL's in a Wordpress blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCLAIMER : Not a WordPress Developer, Just a MySQL DBA

For a given table, say `link_url`

```
mysql> show create table wp_links\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: wp_links
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `wp_links` (
  `link_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `link_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_target` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_visible` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'Y',
  `link_owner` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `link_rating` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `link_updated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `link_rel` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `link_notes` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `link_rss` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`link_id`),
  KEY `link_visible` (`link_visible`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

and you have Amazon Links like this one:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/productcode/?tag=affiliateID-20
```

and you want to replace the number 20 with some other number (like 253) so that URLs are now

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/productcode/?tag=affiliateID-253
```

Run the following SQL script

```
SET @old_number = 20;
SET @new_number = 253;
SET @affiliate_prefix = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/productcode/?tag=affiliateID-';
SET @old_affiliate = CONCAT(@affiliate_prefix ,@old_number);
SET @new_affiliate = CONCAT(@affiliate_prefix ,@new_number);
CREATE TABLE linkids SELECT link_id FROM wp_links WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE linkids ADD PRIMARY KEY;
INSERT INTO linkids SELECT link_id FROM wp_links WHERE link_url=@old_affiliate;
UPDATE linkids A INNER JOIN wp_links B USING (link_id) SET B.link_url=@new_affiliate;
DROP TABLE linkids;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks Rolando, however I want to replace the whole string of affiliateID-##. AffiliateID is actually a string of text that contains the name of the affiliate. For example, a website called hobo might have an affiliate ID of hobo-10 and the string I want to replace it with is memi-20.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with this plugin: [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/).  You can enter the full URL (including the old affiliate ID) and replace it with the full URL including your new affiliate ID.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jared's answer I've used the [Velvet Blues Update URLs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin to you know, update URLs. :) If all the URLs are in the content that should be sufficient.  If you think that some URLs might be lurking in other places, like meta/options then you might want to try the [Serialized PHP Search and Replace script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). I used it recently to move WP to a new server and it was perfect and perfectly simple.  I think either would do you well.